# Scan security-headers on local projects

Tags: security, xss, csrf, owasp, x-frame-options

I like this site a lot

https://securityheaders.com/?q=localhost&followRedirects=on

I want to use it to scan my local project

I can't seem to do that

[image]

Is there a way to check security headers on local project that not live yet ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that with ZAP. The baseline scan (https://github.com/zaproxy/zaproxy/wiki/ZAP-Baseline-Scan) will do that and more - we use that at Mozilla.

Comment: Okay. Let me check if they have it on a Mac OS X 

Comment: ZAP is supported on Windows, Linux and Macs: https://www.zaproxy.org/download/ Its never going to be in the OS X marketplace as its extensible and has its own (free) marketplace.